# Trigger in jQuery with options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have for example:

```
$('#field').click(function(){
   alert('One');
   alert('Two');
})
```

and i would like use trigger:

```
$('#field').trigger('click');
```

is possible to add function for this?

If i use trigger i would like execute only **alert('One');**

Maybe as...

```
$('#field').click(function(){
   alert('One');
   if(this != trigger){
      alert('Two');
   }
})
```

Comment: where you looking for: $('#field').click(my_function(variable));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand you correctly, but you can pass variables to the trigger using the second argument:

```
$('#field').click(function(e, obj) {
    alert('One');
    if ( obj.two ) {
        alert('Two');
    }
});    

$('#field').trigger('click', {
   two: false
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t5nZz/

Comment: For me it alerts "One" then "Two" without me having to click.. -- http://jsfiddle.net/GmYg3/

Comment: @David, yes a typo, it’s the second argument that contains the passed data, not the event object. See my edit. http://jsfiddle.net/t5nZz/

Answer (score 3):

`.trigger` can actually send parameters to the event (it needs to be an array).

```
$('#field').trigger('click', [true]);
```

Then modify the event like so:

```
$('#field').click(function(e, trigger){
   alert('One');
   if(!trigger){
      alert('Two');
   }
})
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/NTICompass/Rkr9S/

Comment: Well, jQuery normalizes the array under the hood in `jQuery.event.trigger` so I assume it’s OK to send an object with keyword arguments instead of an array (wich is kind of ugly anyway). But perhaps following the docs is arguably more "safe"...

Answer (score 1):

In case of triggered event corresponding event object will have a property `isTrigger: true`. So you can do something like this:

```
$('#field').click(function(e) {
   alert('One');
   if (!e.isTrigger) {
      alert('Two');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If i read your question right, you want when its manually triggered to do something different.

Section 1

```
someGlobalVariable = true;
$('#field').trigger('click');
```

Section 2

```
$('#field').click(function(){
   alert('One');
   if(!someGlobalVariable){
      alert('Two');
   }
   someGlobalVariable = false;
})
```